# NodeJS: dockerising with Postgres is complaining that database does not exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am building a Node JS web application. I am using Postgres SQL for the database. I am dockerising the development using docker-compose.yaml.

This is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    container_name: app-web-server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/node/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - primary_app_network
  postgres:
    container_name: app-database
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=docker
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
      - POSTGRES_DB=app_db
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: docker/pgconfig/Dockerfile
    networks:
      - primary_app_network
  pgadmin:
    container_name: app-pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.18
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@linuxhint.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: secret
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 80
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin
    links:
      - 'postgres:pgsql-server'
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - primary_app_network
networks:
  primary_app_network:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  postgres-data:
  pgadmin-data:
```

Then I spin up the environment using docker-compose.yaml. When my application tried to connect to the database it is complaining that the app_database does not exist.

This is docker/pgconfig/Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:11-alpine
# run init.sql on init
ADD ./docker/pgconfig/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.sql
```

This is docker/pgconfig/init.sql

```
SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET default_tablespace = '';
SET default_with_oids = false;

SELECT 'CREATE DATABASE app_db' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'app_db')\gexec
```

This is docker/node/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14-alpine
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add nodejs
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
COPY ../.. /
RUN cd /; npm install;
RUN npm install -g nodemon
EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["npm", "run", "docker-dev"]
```

Why it is complaining that "database "app_db" does not exist"?

Comment: Postgres only uses the environment variables if no database exists when the container starts. You have a mapping of `/var/lib/postgresql/data`, so you might have an existing database there. Try removing the volume mapping or delete the postgres-data volume, so you're sure that it creates a fresh database with the right name.